# Electric Flux through a lamina

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I was wondering what the electric flux would be through a square (or any planar lamina for that matter) if I placed a charge at the centre of the square.

I think that it will be 0 since none of the lines actually pass through the lamina. 
Is my logic correct?

Edit: Just from an examination point of view, can anyone suggest me some other variations of questions of this type that could be asked in an exam or just anything related to this to better my concepts?

Comment: I would simply say that it can't be properly defined, and not worry much about it. There is always a discontinuity in the electric field at a point charge.

Answer (score -1):

There is simple understanding you have to make while seeing any question:

Our main motive is always to make that charge in close gaussian surfaces and we can do that by imagining any closed object.

For sheet if the charge is kept at some finite distance like a/2 so we can imagine 'a' side cube then flux will be:

$$\phi_E = \frac{q}{6E_0} $$

But if let us say if the distance between charge and sheet is tending to zero means there distance is so small. Then on that case we can take that sheet as infinite large sheet. Then flux would be :

$$\phi_E = \frac{q}{2E_0} $$

I guess I don't need to prove the above equation
The logic for that question you mentioned above is correct as no flux will pass through that lamina. We can understand like let us say if you will keep that charge on any face in the cube. Then to find flux at that situation we exclude that face and we find flux which is going through rest of the faces which will be equal to:

$$\phi_E = \frac{1}{5}[\frac{q}{2E_0}]$$